# How to bring ftable to excel in R without a lot of formatting (merge, unquote)

Tags: r, export-to-excel

What I miss about Pandas(Python) working on R is the way a DataFrame is exported to excel.
In R, ftable shows tables similar as pandas multiindex DataFrame. When I use to_excel in pandas every row and column is ok in every cell even merge cells in column names if necesary.

In R I tried write.ftable with write.table

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1:6), b = rep(c('G1','G2'),3), c = rep(c('A','D','F'),2), d = c('F','F','F','F','M','M'))
df2 = ftable(xtabs(a~b+c+d, df), row.vars = 1)
write.table(write.ftable(df2))
```

But I need spend a lot of time formatting (text to column, unquoting, merging, etc) in excel.

There is a way (package) in R to export ftable to excel without to make a lot of formatting things.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, not familiar with how the Python code should work but you can get the same output as printed on the screen by using these commands: `r <- stats:::format.ftable(df2, quote=F) ; write.table(r, "temp.csv", row.names=F, col.names=F, sep=",")`. I dont think it will be straight forward to automagically merge cells. If this is not what you want can you edit your question to show what the csv should look like

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for. With your anser now only need to merge cells in columns. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(xtable)
print(xtable(as.matrix(df2)), type = "html", file = "out.html")
file.show("out.html")
```

Now copy the output and paste it into Excel.

Comment: Could you just use `write.table` on `as.data.frame(as.matrix(df2))` to get the same format?

Comment: No.  `write.table` does not produce HTML.

Comment: ha, i realise...sorry for not being clear. It was more a comment on producing an html file and then *copy the output and paste it into Excel*. I thought the html stage could be bypassed.

Comment: Pasting HTML into Excel maintains the layout.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
library(DescTools)
txt <- stats:::format.ftable(df2, quote=FALSE)
XLView(txt, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes. similar to @user20650 answer but different output. I prefer write.table(txt,"clipboard")

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this to print the output of R into a text file.

```
sink("df2.txt")
df2
sink()
```

After, in Excel, you can use the `File -> Import -> Text file`, then select the `df2.txt`, `Fixed width` and adjust to the format you want.